# Ajax/PHP mailsend script not working

Tags: php, ajax, email

I am using one ajax+php scrip to send mail from html web site. I have this scrip on my other web sites (different servers) and its working fine but now i cant make it to work on my new web site which i am building.
Here is the form which calls the ajax function:

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <table id="tablecontact">
            <tr><th>Name:</th><td><input id="name" type="text" class="input" name="Name" value="" size="30" /></td></tr>
            <tr><th>E-mail:</th><td><input id="email" class="input" name="E-mail" value="" size="30" /></td></tr>
            <tr><th>Subject:</th><td><input id="subject" class="input" name="Subject" value="" size="30" /></td></tr>
            <tr><th>Message:</th><td><textarea id="message" class="input" name="Massege" cols="40" rows="5" style="max-width:700px"></textarea></td></tr> 
            <tr><td colspan="2"><center><input id="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm();" />&nbsp;<input type="button" class="reset" value="Reset" /></center></td></tr>
            </table>
      </form>
```

here is the ajax script:

```
function submitForm() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {         
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
        var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
        var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
        var subject=document.getElementById('subject').value;
        var message=document.getElementById('message').value;
var parameters='name='+name+'&email='+email+'&subject='+subject+'&message='+message;
xmlhttp.open('POST','mailsend.php',true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send(parameters);};
```

here is the mailsend.php:

```
<?php
$pass = validEmail($_POST['email']);
            $subject = $_POST['subject']." : Contact";
            $email = $_POST['email'] ;
            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $message = $_POST['message'] ;
            $headers = "From: $name Email: $email";
if ($pass && strlen($subject)>=5 && strlen($message)>=5 && strlen($name)>=5) 
        {
            $to='MYMAIL';
            $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ;
            if ($sent){ 
            echo('<div id="success"><img src="ok.png" style="margin-top:3px;" /> Your message was sent.</div>');
            $hppmessage='Thanks for contacting.';
            $hppheaders='Auto Replay from: MYMAIL';
            $hppsubject='Contact message received.';
            $sent1= mail($email,$hppsubject,$hppmessage,$hppheaders,'-f MYMAIL');
            } else
            echo ('<div id="error"><img src="error.png" style="margin-top:3px;" /> Error! Please try again.') ;
        } else
        echo ('<div id="error"><img src="error.png" style="margin-top:3px;" /> Error! Please try again.') ;

?>
```

any help will be apreciated, thanks in advance and best wishes.

Comment: Where exactly do you get errors?

Comment: i dont get any errors the code is just not executing.

Answer (score 0):

Its okay but instead use jQuery, Here is a link to the site: http://jquery.com/. jQuery is way more efficient and faster! Once you've included the jQuery script file change your javascript to this:

```
function submitForm(){
   var nameval    = $("#name").val();
   var emailval   = $("#email").val();
   var subjectval = $("#subject").val();
   var messageval = $("#message").val();
   $.post("mailsend.php", { name: nameval, email: emailval, subject :subjectval, message : messageval } );
}
```

Your ajax script came from w3schools which is not a great place for tutorials, instead read the official jQuery docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/.

**EDIT:** Also your $to variable is not a valid email so that may be your problem.

Comment: pointing him to use jquery is not going to solve his problem. Also there is no need to include whole jquery just to make an ajax request. That is not faster it is just less code.

Comment: Less code means less complex and he said his code is not working so I changed it so there shouldn't be any errors and jQuery is proven to be faster!

Comment: Jquery is javascript so it only can be proven to be faster then badly written javascript.

Comment: Correct but ***most*** of the time, pure javascript is written badly (by new comers) and I've edited my post so that it also shows what may be wrong with his PHP.

Comment: thanks for your replys guys, i will try this with jQuery anyway i am using jQery for other elements on the page. $to ='MYMAIL'; i swap on purpose my real mail with MYMAIL since i dont want to post it public to avoid spam. btw when i check the mailsend.php directly its working as it should so it seems like my server is either not configured to send ajax requests or can it be that my server is linus based so it cant send Microsoft.XMLHTTP requests?

Comment: It could just be that the XMLHTTP request isn't working or is broken. Javascript uses the client so it doesn't need the server. That means it wont be linux. See my jQuery example and tell me if it works :)

Comment: nop :( tried with your code its not working, same thing you click the button the page refreshes and no return is received nor the mail is sent :(

Comment: Delete the `<form>` tag as it may be interfering and change your input type="submit" to this `<button onclick="submitForm();">Submit</button>`

Comment: done that and tested. now the page is not refreshing and nothing is happening :( thanks C1D i really appreciate that your trying to help me.

Comment: nop no mail received yet :(
did you test this whole script C1D is it working for you?

Comment: no I don't have a server I can currently test this out on. To see if is getting the right values of the id's try to add console.log(variable name); for each one. Also if you right click, click inspect element, click network and you'll be able to see the network transfers. See if its getting the request and if it is click on it and look at the response to make sure theres no errors!

Comment: if you test it locally it should return error code (not able to connect to smtp server at...) but strangely this web that have the problem doesnt even show any return locally :( it behaves like there is no code behind the button at all.

Comment: Did you check your network requests? Also try remove the `button` tag and replacing it with `div`. I remember I had a problem like this and using div fixed it but I don't know if it'll work in this situation.